# Android Cardview version upgrade changed background color of view

Tags: android, cardview

I updated my gradle dependency version for cardview from

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.0'
```

All  background colors of cardview changed from white to grey.
What should i do to use same white color for all the cardviews?

Answer (score 1):

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
```

Comment: Or `@android:color/white` if he don't have a defined white color.

Comment: What about the users who are already using the app.how can a version upgrade bring such change